# Authentication of arangodb APIs of dbserver and agency is failed

Tags: api, authentication, arangodb

I uses the `arangodb`(0.9.3) to start cluster(current version 3.2.1).

there are some problemsin authentication.

1. `query1`  post to **coordinator**(port=8529) with **basic auth**, response 200

   `curl -X GET \
   http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8529/_db/KnowledgeGraph/_api/collection/CarInfo \
   -H 'authorization: Basic cm9vdDptaHh6a2hs' \
   -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
   -H 'postman-token: 897691e4-c4fc-5588-b217-0da53bc368ba'`
2. `query2` post to **agency**(port=8531) with **basic auth**, response 401

   `curl -X GET \
   http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8531/_api/agency/config \
   -H 'authorization: Basic cm9vdDptaHh6a2hs' \
   -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
   -H 'postman-token: 5160250f-4471-84aa-e377-bd0b99ba9926'`
3. I want to use `logger-follow` to monitor the change of data in cluster. `query3` post to **dbserver**(port=8530) with **basic auth**, response 401. If my cluster start without `--auth.jwt-secret /my/path/to/jwt`, such query has response 200. 

   `curl -X GET \
   'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8530/_api/replication/logger-follow?from=0' \
   -H 'authorization: Basic cm9vdDptaHh6a2hs' \
   -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
   -H 'postman-token: 11b09c7f-85b1-4ed3-ca78-f28cf86c331b'`

Is there some difference of authentication between **agency/dbserver** with **coordinator**?
Or is there something wrong with authentication of **agency/dbserver**?

Comment: There is a difference between coordinators and the rest of the lot. How did you start up your cluster?